# chisq.test on a dataframe

Tags: r, plyr, chi-squared

Hi I really think I am missing something, but I can not figure out how to compute a chisq on a data frame.
I have a data frame like test and I what to compute a chisq to determine if the frequency of a category is higher compare with the entire set.
I also want to perform it for all category.

```
cat  <- c("aa","bb","cc","dd","aa","cc","bb","aa")
variable  <- c(1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
test <- as.data.frame(cbind(cat,variable))
testcast  <- dcast(test, cat~variable)
testcast.sum  <- matrix(c(1,2,3,2),ncol=2,byrow=T)
chisq.test(testcast.sum)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You can perform a chi squared test to check the association between cat and variable like this chisq.test(table(cat,variable)).

I don't understand what you mean by "perform it for all category", though.

Note that with the numbers you have posted the chi squared test might not be a good choice ( see here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-squared_test#Problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Problems) )